# How to setup default browser?

Tags: browser, mime-types

How to change default browser for opening url-s ?

For sanity check, I tried:

```
xdg-open 'http://unix.stackexchange.com'
```

And it opens in other browser. [I found information about assigning applications to filetypes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-open) with `xdg-mime default xpdf.desktop application/pdf` . However I don't know how to apply this knowledge for `url` ? Does `url` have mimetype ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to change the default application opened for URLs
The easy way to change this is using `gnome-control-center info` and changing the default application.

Yes, the schema type is

```
x-scheme-handler/http=
x-scheme-handler/https=
```

each followed by the application.desktop you want to open http

[Here](http://pastebin.com/QvdDE2yk) is a sample mimeapps.list with chromium as the http app

Comment: I've assigned firefox with `xdg-mime default firefox.desktop 'x-scheme-handler/http'`... resulting in : `cat ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list` = `[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/https=firefox.desktop
x-scheme-handler/http=firefox.desktop` , however it is still assigned to chrome when I run `xdg-open 'http://unix.stackexchange.com'`

Comment: I had the exact same experience with the `xdg-settings` and `xdg-mime default`, even restarting the desktop, logging out/in didn't have the desired effect. But `gnome-control-center info` succeeded in changing from chromium to firefox and back again. xdg-open uses specified default.

Comment: Thanks ! In my case I needed to run **KDE Control Center** with `systemsettings`

Answer (score 3):

Using [xdg-utils](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xdg-utils-mimeo/):

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser brave-beta-bin.desktop
```

If you don't know the desktop file associated with your favourite browser, then use [mimeo](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mimeo/):

```
➜ mimeo --app2desk brave-beta        
brave-beta
  brave-beta-bin.desktop
```

In this case, I am using the beta version of the brave browser, so I specified the command used to start the browser, and mimeo is able to find the associated desktop file.

#### Testing

```
➜ mimeo --mime2desk x-scheme-handler/http 
x-scheme-handler/http
  brave-beta-bin.desktop

➜ mimeo --mime2desk x-scheme-handler/https
x-scheme-handler/https
  brave-beta-bin.desktop

➜ xdg-open https://google.com         

~ via ⬢ v13.10.1 
➜ Opening in existing browser session.
```